# How can I put one value in another list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

My program needs to accept inputs from the user, but the input is like `Ted,24` , so every input will be separated by comma and I know putting them in a list will be a great idea but I also need to get the average age. Here's my code so far:

```
namesAge = []
count = 0
ave = 0
total = 0

while True:
    mess=input("Enter name and age: ")
    if mess == "":
        print(namesAge)
        print ("We have ",count," names")
        print ("Total age is",total)
        break
    if "," in mess:
        namesAge.append(mess)
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print("invalid input")
```

Comment: Doesn't work.. Hmmmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namesAge = []

while True:
    mess=input("Enter name and age: ")
    if mess == "":
        print(namesAge)
        print ("We have {} names".format(len(namesAge)))
        print ("average age is {}".format(sum(namesAge)/len(namesAge))))
        break
    elif "," in mess:
        name, age = mess.split(',')
        namesAge.append(int(age))
    else:
        print("invalid input")
```

Comment: what you need is a list of ages, then call sum() i think that will very simple

Comment: @ZedrickLloydTenorio update the answer, I think remove the `total` variable is OK now.